# cairo: plotting everything in a space from 0 to 1 both in x and y and only in the end rescale to a certain resolution (resizable window)

Tags: python, plot, resize, gtk, cairo

I am using cairo with GTK+ in python. By using the `expose` event I manage to have a resizable version of what I want to plot, by multiplying values from 0 to 1 to the resolution of the canvas.

I wonder: is it possible to avoid the resizing in every plot function by plotting everything in a 0 to 1 space (both for the x and the y) and then, only with a final "magic" trick, resizing everything that has been plotted to the desired resolution?

Comment: What version of GTK+ is this? And I'm pretty sure you can use a cairo transform to do this...

Comment: @andlabs: The version is 2.latest, can you please add some details on how you would use the transform?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `matplotlib` to plot the graphs, which scales the plot automatically. I haven't done this yet, but I believe you can [configure it to draw](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk.html) to a `GTK widget` (with `GtkAgg`)

If it's just the scaling you're worried about, don't normalize to the range of 0-1. Just calculate the scale factor at the moment of the `expose()` event, and use the [cairo functions](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html) to move/scale the plot.